# "HTTP error" when running composer update

Tags: composer-php

I'm on Windows 7. I get this error on `composer update`:

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015-07%24eec61011fe6ec03b5dc7d406c70116caac2c28b7cb520e5a11a900b4afe8af7b.j
  son" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

composer self-update

```
 You are already using composer version edf14dab1561096c10c71c7dfd81597ff94995a7.
```

Same error everytime.

Comment: Please clear composer cache and check firewall and proxy restrictions.. can you access the URL in your browser?

Comment: I have cleared composer cache and I can access the url in the browser but I still get the same error. Thanks.